Getting Syntax error when bundling and minifying Bootstrap 5 CSS Template
I am using a bootstrap 5 template (I have the minified version), which looks like this. This file is generated using gulp:

I want to include this file in ASP.NET MVC 5 bundle, as it adds the cache busting version to the URL. MVC bundler tried to minify the file, but I don't know why the minification throws error:
This is MVC bundler produce:

This is the error:

Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.

I guess the MVC minification process does not recognize the syntax of my Bootstrap 5 template?
How can I fix this issue? I guess I don't need to minify the file, but I still need to add the cache busting version to the URL.

If you want to Minify and Bundle the stylesheet use StyleBundle class, but if you only want to bundle them without minification then use Bundle class.
bundle:
// the following file is already minified, so use bundle
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/css-theme").Include(
    "~/path-to-css/theme.min.css"));

bundling and minify:
// the following file would be minified and them placed in a bundle
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css-theme").Include(
    "~/path-to-css/theme.css"));

JavaScript
In case of JavaScript files, you can use ScriptBundle to bundle and minify or just Bundle for bundling.
I found this information here.
